# Laravel 5 Where Query

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to make a search function with laravel 5. But I can't get objects with LIKE.

This is my code.

```
public function search(){
        $term = Input::get('search');

        $employees = Auth::user()->employees;

        $results = $employees->where('name','LIKE', 'murat')->all();

        return $results;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some records that you would be expecting?

Answer (score 1):

All relationships also serve as query builders, you can add further constraints to which `employees` are retrieved by calling the `employees()` method and continuing to chain conditions onto the query.

So your function would be like:

```
public function search(){
    $term = Input::get('search');

    $results = Auth::user()->employees()->where('name','LIKE', 'murat')->all();

    return $results;
}
```